# How to properly serialize a VersionedEntity?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-lemon

I have an entity like this :

```
@Entity
public class Shop extends VersionedEntity<User, Long> {
    @Column
    private String name;
    @Column
    private String url;
    @Column
    private String status;
    private String description;
```

I'm now trying to serialize a List of shops, then I got this :

```
)]}',
[{"id":1,"createdDate":{"year":2016,"dayOfMonth":6,"dayOfWeek":3,"era":1,"dayOfYear":97,"weekOfWeekyear":14,"secondOfMinute":38,"millisOfSecond":0,"centuryOfEra":20,"yearOfEra":2016,"yearOfCentury":16,"weekyear":2016,"monthOfYear":4,"hourOfDay":0,"minuteOfHour":8,"millisOfDay":518000,"secondOfDay":518,"minuteOfDay":8,"millis":1459897718000,"zone":{"fixed":false,"uncachedZone":{"fixed":false,"cachable":true,"id":"Africa/Casablanca"},"id":"Africa/Casablanca"},"chronology":{"zone":{"fixed":false,"uncachedZone":{"fixed":false,"cachable":true,"id":"Africa/Casablanca"},"id":"Africa/Casablanca"}},"afterNow":false,"beforeNow":true,"equalNow":false},"lastModifiedDate":{"year":2016,"dayOfMonth":6,"dayOfWeek":3,"era":1,"dayOfYear":97,"weekOfWeekyear":14,"secondOfMinute":38,"millisOfSecond":0,"centuryOfEra":20,"yearOfEra":2016,"yearOfCentury":16,"weekyear":2016,"monthOfYear":4,"hourOfDay":0,"minuteOfHour":8,"millisOfDay":518000,"secondOfDay":518,"minuteOfDay":8,"millis":1459897718000,"zone":{"fixed":false,"uncachedZone":{"fixed":false,"cachable":true,"id":"Africa/Casablanca"},"id":"Africa/Casablanca"},"chronology":{"zone":{"fixed":false,"uncachedZone":{"fixed":false,"cachable":true,"id":"Africa/Casablanca"},"id":"Africa/Casablanca"}},"afterNow":false,"beforeNow":true,"equalNow":false},"version":0,"name":"Shop Name","url":"shop1","status":"Active","description":"Shop description","new":false},{"id":3,"createdDate":{"year":2016,"dayOfMonth":6,"dayOfWeek":3,"era":1,"dayOfYear":97,"weekOfWeekyear":14,"secondOfMinute":57,"millisOfSecond":0,"centuryOfEra":20,"yearOfEra":2016,"yearOfCentury":16,"weekyear":2016,"monthOfYear":4,"hourOfDay":0,"minuteOfHour":9,"millisOfDay":597000,"secondOfDay":597,"minuteOfDay":9,"millis":1459897797000,"zone":{"fixed":false,"uncachedZone":{"fixed":false,"cachable":true,"id":"Africa/Casablanca"},"id":"Africa/Casablanca"},"chronology":{"zone":{"fixed":false,"uncachedZone":{"fixed":false,"cachable":true,"id":"Africa/Casablanca"},"id":"Africa/Casablanca"}},"afterNow":false,"beforeNow":true,"equalNow":false},"lastModifiedDate":{"year":2016,"dayOfMonth":6,"dayOfWeek":3,"era":1,"dayOfYear":97,"weekOfWeekyear":14,"secondOfMinute":57,"millisOfSecond":0,"centuryOfEra":20,"yearOfEra":2016,"yearOfCentury":16,"weekyear":2016,"monthOfYear":4,"hourOfDay":0,"minuteOfHour":9,"millisOfDay":597000,"secondOfDay":597,"minuteOfDay":9,"millis":1459897797000,"zone":{"fixed":false,"uncachedZone":{"fixed":false,"cachable":true,"id":"Africa/Casablanca"},"id":"Africa/Casablanca"},"chronology":{"zone":{"fixed":false,"uncachedZone":{"fixed":false,"cachable":true,"id":"Africa/Casablanca"},"id":"Africa/Casablanca"}},"afterNow":false,"beforeNow":true,"equalNow":false},"version":0,"name":"shop3","url":"shop3","status":"ACTIVE","description":"Shop description, from ShopService","new":false}]
```

I understand those disturbingly long dates come from `createdDate` and `lastModifiedDate` which I inherited from `VersionedEntity`.

How do I avoid getting them in this output ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Annotating `Shop` class with

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "createdDate", "lastModifiedDate" })
```

should work, I think.

Comment: I ended up doing this : @JsonIgnoreProperties({ "createdDate", "createdBy", "lastModifiedDate", "lastModifiedBy", "version", "new" })